# Process microsoft DOT/DOTX file and save as microsoft DOCX : Electron JS

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium

In electron application, I need to convert dot/dotx file to docx with filled Database data -

1) On button, click select the dot/dotm file

2) after file selection opens the selected dot/dotm file with replacement of placeholder/variables from API json format data.

3) on save, the opened file execute the next code from where the file has been opened in electron.

Means code execution cursor should wait for file data replacement and save in electron.

Any solution for this!